# How to pass arguments to a bash file in the docker ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've a dockerfile where I use a custom entrypoint.sh. In this file I want to use the ARGS which I pass from docker-compose to the dockerfile.

The problem is that I don't get the content of the variable to the dockerfile I just get the variable name.

For example:

```
ARGS ENVIROMENT=production
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/html/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["${ENVIROMENT}"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/html
composer update
echo $1;
```

The echo $1 show "${Enviroment}" instead of "production" what I expect.

Comment: why not use all the thing in CMD? CMD ["/var/www/html/entrypoint.sh", "${ENVIROMENT}"]

Answer (score 1):

Ouch ! You've hit a sensible point of Docker with this question.

But first, let me clarify some point here :

- First of all, you have a typo in your example. It's `ARG` not `ARGS`
- `ARG` allows you to define a *build-time variable*. Meaning that this variable will only be usefull when doing a `docker image build` command. You'll then be able to override it with `--build-arg`. For example :

```
docker image build --build-arg ENVIROMENT=integration ...`
```

- At the opposite, `ENV` allows you to define an environment variable which can be used during runtime.

You can find all the info you need in the official documentation for [env](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) and [arg](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

#### Now, back to the point...

To make it simple:

- Do not use both **ENTRYPOINT** and **CMD** when you want to pass some environment variable to your entrypoint from your cmd. It's just a pain. Really.
- When you want to use a environment variable inside **CMD**, then you'll have to either use bash format, or to prefix the command with `sh -c` for exec format :

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo ${GREETINGS}"]
#or
CMD echo ${GREETINGS}
```

Here is a Dockerfile that works with both syntax (just uncomment the **CMD** you want to use) :

```
FROM debian:8
ENV GREETINGS="hello world"
#CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo ${GREETINGS}"]
#CMD echo ${GREETINGS}
```

You can find more detailled info on those issues :

- [Issue 5509](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5509)
- [Issue 34772](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34772)

Comment: Nice explanation about the CMD/ENTRYPOINT with arguments issue, but your answer is missing how to include the ARG from the question. To see how to solve this, see my answer.

Comment: @TobiasThieron, you're right. I felt that `ARG` was not the ideal solution, that's why i did only put an example with `ENV`.  Your solution is ok, but in my opinion it is just sugar if the value is only used inside `CMD`. Of course, if we need the value during both build time and runtime, then we'll have to do as you shown.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the pros and cons about both solutions. Your solution is good, but only usable if you overwrite the ENV value in the Dockerfile before each build. And that's not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complete Marc abouchacra's answer.
What is still missing is how to use the ARG command.

A possible solution could be:

```
ARG ENVIRONMENT=production
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT 
CMD exec /var/www/html/entrypoint.sh $ENVIRONMENT
```

The exec is there to make sure your entrypoint.sh is the process with the PID=1.